# Download HAR file using script from Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, har

I want to download the HAR file containing all the resources information that the browser downloads for a particular site. Currently, I am opening a webpage on Chrome through Python Script. Now, I want my script to automatically download HAR file after Complete Webpage is loaded.
I have already searched through many sources, but didn't find anything useful.
Any help will be appreciated.